# print to line X+1, not to the next page using tcpdf in php

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am doing a programming to print data using tcpdf. The requirement is as follow: after printing transactions until line X, for example after line 10, the printing process is stopped, because there no data anymore. Then, if I want to print again, for example after 2 months, and there are 10 data transactions, then the data will appear in the X+1 line, not in the next page.

This is the case in printing transaction in passbook.

What I have done is that, every time I start printing, the data will appear on the next page, not the next line.

Thank you. (note: sorry, for my poor English).

Comment: Have you gone through the docs ?   http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a5171e20b366b74523709d84c349c1ced

Comment: I am not sure about what method to use. This is my idea: I must keep the current top margin after printing X lines? Then, set the top margin (x+1) first before next printing?